# как в Excel Отключить обрезание чисел больших

Tags: excel

Чтобы они отображались не так в графике 2E+09 а нормально в десятиричной системе без сокращений

Comment: эмм.... установить «формат ячейки»?

Comment: Обычно Excel автоматически переходит на научный формат, если на обычный нехватает места в поле... попробуй раздвинуть границы отображения значения.

Comment: Он не может показать точное число так как число слишком большое для компьютера.

Comment: @Akina Если число не входит в ячейку, то показывается #####, а не научный формат.

Comment: @Duoxx 2ккк - не слишком большое.

Comment: @Эникейщик Вот кабы своими глазами не видел - до сих пор бы думал так же...

Comment: @Akina Оказывается от формата ячейки зависит. Если "Стандартный", то переводит в научную запись, а если "Число", то показывает #####.

Comment: @Эникейщик, и это логично: формат задан строгий - *Число*, *Excel* не может вольничать. При *Общем*  он подбирает подходящий формат (по его мнению)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не соответствует тематике ресурса

Answer (score 2):

Первое, что нужно учитывать: формат значения и формат ячейки - не одно и то же.

То, что видим (*2E+09*) - экспоненциальная форма записи числа 2000000000 (не только этого, см. ниже). Это же число можно получить:

```
=2*10^9
=2*1e9
```

Число не обрезано, но отображается в другом виде. Значение в нормальном его виде  можно посмотреть в строке формул.

Но вот незадача... 2100000000 в экспоненциальной форме будет иметь ту же запись - *2E+09*. А все потому, что формат ячейки выставлен *Экспоненциальный*, да еще и с нулевым количеством знаков в дробной части. Ставим два знака после запятой - получаем *2,10E+09*

*Excel* сравнивает значение с заданными форматами и сам определяет, как его отображать. Иногда "зло шутит". Например, запись *1.02* (не в текстовой ячейке) воспринимается как дата *день.месяц.(текущий_год)*, *11.22* -  как дата *месяц.день.(текущий_год)*. При этом *Excel* меняет не только формат отображения - он еще и значение изменит! Вместо введенного *1.02* получим дату *01.02.2018*. Или, если установим формат ячейки *Общий*, увидим 43132 (количество дней после *01.01.1900*)

Формат ячейки мог автоматически измениться на экспоненциальный в случае, когда ширина ячейки была недостаточна для отображения полного числа. Мог подтянуться при копировании данных.

Исправить "обрезанное" просто: задать достаточную ширину ячейки, задать ей формат *Общий* или *Числовой* с необходимым количеством знаков после запятой.

**Важное примечание.** Большие числа все же обрезаются, но это не связано с экспоненциальной формой записи.

*Excel* имеет ограничение при работе с числовыми данными - не более 15 разрядов. Если в ячейку вписать число *12345678901234567890*, получим значение с обнуленными младшими разрядами - *12345678901234500000*, от *1,2345678901234567890* останется *1,23456789012345*.

Избежать обрезания можно, если установить текстовый формат ячейки. Текстом может храниться и длинное число. Это тоже бывает нужно: банковские счета, инвентарные номера... Т.е. фатически не числа, а текст, состоящий из цифр. Но использовать такие значения в качестве чисел не получится - при первой же попытке младшие разряды обнулятся.

Ради справедливости нужно отметить, что работать можно и с очень большими числами, разрядность которых превышает 15: хранить значения как текст, при использовании делить на допустимые фрагменты... Но это непросто и выходит за рамки вопроса.